# Poisson Bracket $\{\delta_{ij}, g\}$ and partial derivative of Kronecker delta

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, poisson-brackets

I am currently working through Shankar's Princeiple of Quantum Mechanics

Exercise 2.8.2 is to verify that the infinitesimal transformation generated by any dynamical
variable g is a canonical transformation. (i.e. the following is a canonical transformation)

$$q_{i} \rightarrow \bar{q_{i}} = q_{i} + \epsilon \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial p_{i}}$$
$$p_{i} \rightarrow \bar{p_{i}} = p_{i} + \epsilon \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial q_{i}}.$$

As part of my answer I got to the following :

$$\{q_{i} + \delta q_{i}, p_{j} + \delta p_{j}\} = \delta_{ij} + \epsilon\{\delta_{ij}, g\}.$$

Which makes me assume $\epsilon\{\delta_{ij}, g\} = 0$, and I found an answer online which simply states this result as part of the proof.

Why is this the case? I am unsure how to handle an object like $\dfrac{\partial \delta_{ij}}{\partial q_{k}}$. Is it well-defined ? Is it simply 0, due to being a function of $i$ and $j $?

EDIT : Checking whether $\{q_{i} + \delta q_{i}, p_{j} + \delta p_{j}\} = \delta_{ij}$

Expand brackets and use $\delta \omega = \epsilon \{ \omega, g\}$:
$$\{q_{i} + \delta q_{i}, p_{j} + \delta p_{j}\} = \{q_{i}, p_{j}\} + \epsilon \{\{q_{i}, g\}, p_{j}\} + \epsilon \{q_{i}, \{p_{j}, g\}\} + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^{2})$$

Ignoring $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^{2})$ since $\epsilon$ is infinitesimal, and using the fact the Poisson Bracket is anti-commutative,

$$\{q_{i} + \delta q_{i}, p_{j} + \delta p_{j}\} = \{q_{i}, p_{j}\} + \epsilon \{\{q_{i}, g\}, p_{j}\} + \epsilon \{\{g, p_{j}\}, q_{i}\}$$

With the Jacobi identity :

$$\{q_{i} + \delta q_{i}, p_{j} + \delta p_{j}\} = \{q_{i}, p_{j}\} - \epsilon \{\{p_{j}, q_{i}\}, g\}$$

Inserting $\{q_{i}, p_{j}\} = \delta_{ij}$

$$\{q_{i} + \delta q_{i}, p_{j} + \delta p_{j}\} = \{q_{i}, p_{j}\} + \epsilon \{\delta_{ij}, g\}$$

Comment: I also did the 3 cases separately. In the third case I expanded out the brackets, ignored the term in $\epsilon^{2}$ and used the Jacobi identity. I'll add details to my question

Comment: Can you put the steps of how you got to this part in the answer?

Comment: Just finished expanding my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kronecker deltas are simply constants, being either $1$ or $0$ depending on the values of $i$ and $j$. An expression like $\{q_{i} + \delta q_{i}, p_{j} + \delta p_{j}\} = \delta_{ij} - \epsilon\{\delta_{ij}, g\}$ should really be thought of as $9$ different expressions for each possible value of $i$ and $j$, and in each of those expressions the Kronecker delta becomes a simple constant.

Comment: Thank you, thinking of it as 9 expressions makes it much more intuitive